# How can I add bootstrap popover binding to my HTML?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, svg, ng-bootstrap

I have a `SVG` which has a `rect` element inside on clicking the rect I see an alert.

I want to replace it with a [bootstrap popover](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/examples), like the button below, How can I do that ? It has to be with code not HTML

**Here is the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2spr3a) of the problem I am trying to solve**

```
    import { Component, Input, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `

  <svg #mySvg width="400" height="400">
</svg>
<br> <br><br>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mr-2" placement="right"
        ngbPopover="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." popoverTitle="Popover on top">
  Should Mimic this
</button>

  `,
  styles: [`svg {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}`]
})
export class HelloComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() name: string;
  @ViewChild('mySvg', { static: false }) mySvg: ElementRef;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    const svg = this.mySvg.nativeElement;
    const svgNS = svg.namespaceURI;
    const rect = this.renderer.createElement('rect', svgNS);
    const clickedOnRect = () => {
      alert('Rectangle was clicked');
    }

    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', '100');
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', '100');
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', '100');
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', '100');
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', "transparent");
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', "red");
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-width', '5');
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'tab-index', '1');
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'cursor', 'pointer');
    rect.addEventListener('click', ($event) => {
      clickedOnRect();
    });

    svg.appendChild(rect);
  }
}
```

**Note**: I want to attach popover to the `rect` element not `svg`

Comment: Why don't you just apply the attributes to the `svg` element? Seems to work fine: https://angular-irou2w.stackblitz.io

Comment: in my app I draw different shapes inside svg  each shape has to have an popover so on the whole svg it wont work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if this can be done in angular way i.e ng-bootstrap. Alternatively you can use simple bootstrap and add the popover pragmatically.So first add files required by bootstrap on your index.html page(i have skkiped adding css as css is alredy included in ndb)

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Then in your component

```
declare var $ ;

$(react).popover({content:'Rectangle was clicked'});
```

[Working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-owqmqh)

Comment: @dota2pro as per your edit `I want to attach popover to the rect element not svg` you can change `$(svg)` to `$(rect)` working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wq5dxd

Comment: @dota2pro check out updated stackblitz demo it working fine with two react elements